# SQL - calculate % increase?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have data that looks like the below

```
ID  Name     Startdate     Fee     Increase     IncreaseDate 
23  PEN      01/08/2018    £65       Yes          01/12/2018 
33  PEL      02/06/2018    £100      No              NULL
```

I need to produce an output showing the "Fee" of each row, broken down by Year (Need this to go as far as 2019)

If the Increase flag is set to Yes then a 7% increase will be added to the Fee column from the "Increase date". The fee will then increase by 7% on the anniversary of each "Increase date". An ideal output would look like the below with the year columns being string format.

```
ID  Name     Startdate     2018                          2019  
23  PEN      01/08/2018    £65, £69.55 from 01/12/2018   £69.55, £74.41 from 01/12/2019 
33  PEL      02/06/2018    £100                          £100
```

Can anyone help with the best way to achieve this? Thank you.

Using sql server 2016

Jess

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: What's up with the values for (what I assume) is the 3% increase? `£65, £69.55 from 01/12/2018` & `£69.55, £74.41 from 01/12/2019` They appear to be **much closer** to 7% (and some change)

Comment: Sorry, was actually meant to be 7% yes. Using sql server 2016.

Comment: Also, you should split up the columns...[2018 Fee] £65, [2018 Fee Increase] £4.55, [2018 Fee Increase Date] 01/12/2018.  You don't want to combine them all in one field.

Comment: How many years out?  Fixed percentage increase each year?

Comment: up to 2022 would be useful, and yes fixed percentage

Comment: @jd8766 . . . I don't get what the result set looks like.  Can you show the first few rows at least?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably how I would go about accomplishing this:

*Setup (the CTE is not necesary for your purposes, but was used for testing on my end):*

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @YearCounter INT = Year(GetDate())
DECLARE @FinalDate INT = Year(DateAdd(year, 3, GetDate()))

;WITH CTE (ID, Name, StartDate, Fee, Increase, IncreaseDate) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('23','PEN','1/8/2018',65,'Yes', '01/12/2018'), 
            ('33','PEL','2/6/2018',100,'No', Null)
    ) AS A (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6)
)
```

*Query:*

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP001
FROM CTE 

SELECT 
@SQL = 'SELECT ID,
    Name, 
    StartDate, 
    Fee as Orig_Fee, 
    IncreaseDate, '

;WITH years (years, interest) AS
   (SELECT @YearCounter AS years,
    CAST('(Fee*1.07)' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS interest
    UNION ALL
    SELECT years + 1 AS years, 
        interest + ' * ' + '(1.07)' AS interest
    FROM years
    WHERE years.years <= @FinalDate)

SELECT 
@SQL = @SQL + 
    'CASE 
        WHEN Increase = ''Yes'' THEN 
            CAST(ROUND(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), interest) + ', 2, 1) AS DECIMAL(38, 2)) 
        ELSE Fee
    END AS [Fee_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), years) + '], '
FROM years

SELECT
@SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL)-1) + '
FROM #TEMP001 '

EXEC (@SQL)

DROP TABLE #TEMP001
```

A couple of things to note:

1. The `ROUND` I used in the query drops excess beyond the second decimal place, if you require rounding up, switch the `CAST(ROUND(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), interest) + ', 2, 1) AS DECIMAL(38, 2))` to `CAST(ROUND(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), interest) + ', 2) AS DECIMAL(38, 2))`. But based on your results, it looks like you wanted to drop them.
2. It seems like the way you are trying to structure your returns (per year) is abnormal, instead I split these up into different columns, avoiding reiterating several points that seemed unneeded. *For instance, you can simply combine these columns to create what you are looking for from this product.*
3. The Future years can be changed by editing the line `DECLARE @FinalDate INT = Year(DateAdd(year, 3, GetDate()))` from `3` to any number. This is changing it to three years (+1) into the future (or 2022)

*Expected Output:*

```
+----+------+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| ID | Name | StartDate | Orig_Fee | IncreaseDate | Fee_2018 | Fee_2019 | Fee_2020 | Fee_2021 | Fee_2022 |
+----+------+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 23 | PEN  | 1/8/2018  |       65 | 01/12/2018   |    69.55 |    74.41 |    79.62 |    85.20 |    91.16 |
| 33 | PEL  | 2/6/2018  |      100 | NULL         |   100.00 |   100.00 |   100.00 |   100.00 |   100.00 |
+----+------+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Best of luck beyond this.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for this it was a great help. I have 1 other question - what could I do if the increase didn't happen yearly but instead happened after a dynamic amount of time. For example, in the above example the ID 23 would have an additional column called Months, this would be populated with 60. How could I get the increase to only be applied after 60 months?

Thanks
Jess

Comment: @jd8766 There's no real easy way to adapt things in the current state of the query. It *may* be beneficial to ask another question regarding this problem instead. But, if you were terribly inclined to fiddle with the query I wrote, you could try and edit the `years` CTE, to move from `+ 1` to `+ 5`, which would handle the 60 month change. the problem is you would need to change the `@FinalDate` reference as well (year > month and 3 > 60). But if you wanted to handle it dynamically, the change would be too large to really explain without another question.

Answer (score 1):

This the start. It will pull out all the fee increases from 2019 to 2022. It does assume that any record that satisfies `Increase = 'Yes'` will increase in each year of the stated range.

```
    SELECT 
    INTO #temp 
            ID 
        ,   Name
        ,   Startdate 
        ,   Fee As [BaseFee]
        ,   to_char(IncreaseDate, 'mon-dd') as [IncreaseDate]
        ,   Fee * (1.07) AS [Fee2018] 
        ,   Fee * POWER(1.07,2) AS [Fee2019] 
        ,   Fee * POWER(1.07,3) AS [Fee2020] 
        ,   Fee * POWER(1.07,4) AS [Fee2021]
        ,   Fee * POWER(1.07,5) AS [Fee2022]
    FROM {table_name} AS t 
    WHERE t.Increase = 'Yes';


    SELECT 
            ID 
        ,   Name 
        ,   Startdate 
        ,   CAST(BaseFee AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST([Fee2018] AS VARCHAR) + ' from ' + CAST(IncreaseDate AS VARCHAR) AS [2018]
        ,   CAST([Fee2018] AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST([Fee2019] AS VARCHAR) + ' from ' + CAST(DATEADD(year, 1, IncreaseDate) AS VARCHAR) AS [2019]
        ,   CAST([Fee2019] AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST([Fee2020] AS VARCHAR) + ' from ' + CAST(DATEADD(year, 2, IncreaseDate) AS VARCHAR) AS [2020]
        ,   CAST([Fee2020] AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST([Fee2021] AS VARCHAR) + ' from ' + CAST(DATEADD(year, 3, IncreaseDate) AS VARCHAR) AS [2021]
        ,   CAST([Fee2021] AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST([Fee2022] AS VARCHAR) + ' from ' + CAST(DATEADD(year, 4, IncreaseDate) AS VARCHAR) AS [2022]
    FROM #temp;
Drop #temp;
```

Additional logic would be needed to check the `[IncreaseDate]` and then adjust the yearly output accordingly.

Will all the records have fee increases in 2018?